# Open SOAP Connection every hour using Windows Task Service

Tags: php, api, soap, task, scheduler

I'm having trouble understanding how Windows Task Service works. I would like to open a SOAP connection every hour and do its thing.

I came  across a few site with how to do it.

1) http://www.redolivedesign.com/utah-web-designers-blog/2007/11/17/how-to-run-a-php-or-asp-file-on-a-schedule-with-windows-xmlhttp-object-and-scheduled-tasks/

2) http://amitdhamu.com/blog/automating-php-using-task-scheduler/

My questions are:

1) which link should I lean toward to?
2) my SOAP connection file is on my server. In the 'Start a Program' in task scheduler, how would I add my ftp script here? or does it have to be in the local machine?

Answer (score 0):

One usually does not "open a soap connection" every once in a while. The SOAP server is running all the time, waiting for requests, so if you want to grab some data from the server, you'd probably "send a soap request every hour" or "make a soap call" as a client.

If the server should only answer requests in a time window every hour, the server would still be running all the time, but the internal code would deny responses beyond "business hours" of that service. Which would be an unusual setup.

So I think you'd really need to run a client script, and that would be easier. First make sure when running the script manually, it does all the things you need. It must be able to run where you need the result.

And then the question is: How to start it automatically, and which operating system is installed on that machine?

Your first link sets up something that sends an HTTP request to a machine. This would work if you have a server, the server has the script, and you have no way to setup a cronjob there, but need the data on that server.

Your second link sets up the script execution on the machine itself. So the script is on that machine, and the data ends up being there, too.

And I cannot answer your second question, because I don't know what your need really is.